# Excel add-ins ribbon click XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x800c0019, Security certificate required to access this resource is invalid

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins, office365api

I have created excel add-ins using office.js, javascript, react etc. I have created ribbon and wants to enable disable ribbon menu conditionally. The code and manifest which I created is working fine on chrome and edge but with IE and desktop browser it's not working. On IE/desktop excel found error on console on click of ribbon menu.
**XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x800c0019, Security certificate required to access this resource is invalid.**

Created ribbon as per suggested in link:
[excel-shared-runtime-scenario](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-OfficeAddins/tree/main/Samples/excel-shared-runtime-scenario). In this link at read me section it is mentioned "The addin needs HTTPS website. Please run npx office-addin-dev-certs install --days 365 to install dev certificates." So the given example from this link working fine when I install this certificate.

**But this certificate I can not use in my own local development. Please help to understand do I need to create certificate for this? if yes how I can create it as I am new to office.js.
what if I need to move this code on Azure env how I can move this certificate on Azure.**

PSB section from manifest:

```
<Group id="LoginGroup">
                            <Label resid="LoginGroup.Label"/>
                            <Icon>
                                <bt:Image size="16" resid="LGButton.Icon"/>
                                <bt:Image size="32" resid="LGButton.Icon"/>
                                <bt:Image size="80" resid="LGButton.Icon"/>
                            </Icon>
                            <Control xsi:type="Button" id="BtnLoginService">
                                <Label resid="BtnLoginService.Label" />
                                <Supertip>
                                    <!-- ToolTip title. resid must point to a ShortString resource. -->
                                    <Title resid="BtnLoginService.Label" />
                                    <!-- ToolTip description. resid must point to a LongString resource. -->
                                    <Description resid="BtnLoginService.Tooltip" />
                                </Supertip>
                                <Icon>
                                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="LGButton.Icon"/>
                                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="LGButton.Icon"/>
                                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="LGButton.Icon"/>
                                </Icon>
                                <!-- This is what happens when the command is triggered (E.g. click on the Ribbon). Supported actions are ExecuteFunction or ShowTaskpane. -->
                                <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                                    <FunctionName>btnloginservice</FunctionName>
                                </Action>
                            </Control>
                            <Control xsi:type="Button" id="BtnLogoutService">
                                <Label resid="BtnLogoutService.Label" />
                                <Supertip>
                                    <!-- ToolTip title. resid must point to a ShortString resource. -->
                                    <Title resid="BtnLogoutService.Label" />
                                    <!-- ToolTip description. resid must point to a LongString resource. -->
                                    <Description resid="BtnLogoutService.Tooltip" />
                                </Supertip>
                                <Icon>
                                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="SignOutButton.Icon"/>
                                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="SignOutButton.Icon"/>
                                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="SignOutButton.Icon"/>
                                </Icon>
                                <!-- This is what happens when the command is triggered (E.g. click on the Ribbon). Supported actions are ExecuteFunction or ShowTaskpane. -->
                                <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                                    <FunctionName>btnlogoutservice</FunctionName>
                                </Action>
                                <Enabled>false</Enabled>
                            </Control>
                        </Group>
```

Command.js code for functionName:

```
export function btnloginservice(event) {
    console.log('Open login dialog');
    g.state.isMenuEnabled = true;
    updateRibbon();
    enableButton();
    SetRuntimeVisibleHelper(true);
    event.completed();
}

export function btnlogoutservice(event) {
    console.log('Open login dialog');
    g.state.isMenuEnabled = false;
    updateRibbon();
    btnCloseTaskpane(event);
}
```

**I am completely blocked here. Appreciate your help over here.
Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 0):

An Office Add-in is a web application. Unless Microsoft's documentation says otherwise, you do things the same way that you would for any other web application. Search the Internet for information about how to obtain and use HTTPS certificates in web applications.

Also, you **can** use the certficate generated by the `npx` command in your own local development. It is not restricted to just the sample.

Comment: Thanks Rick, "npx office-addin-dev-certs install" solves my issue for local development.